# Slim 3.11 Callable Resolver TypeError

Tags: php, slim-3

I can't find my mistake.  I am getting the follow TypeError when I try a route in my slim api.
the error is:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController::__construct() must be an
>   instance of PDO, instance of Slim\Container given

the constructor for this controller is:

```
public function __construct(\PDO $db, \MongoDB\Client $mongo, \Monolog\Logger $applogger, \Monolog\Logger $seclogger)
```

and the DI Factory that I put into the container is:

```
$container['FacultyController'] = function($c) {
    return new FacultyController($c->get('db'), $c->get('mongo'), $c->get('appLogger'), $c->get('secLogger'));
};
```

I have tried setting each to it's own variable and passing in those variables but same effect.  I've ran a successful test that just loads the slim app and checks that the container has an object of class FacultyController and that it has the messages that I have one that controller so I am 99% sure that the controller is actually getting put into the container.  I think something might be off with the route.  I have both a construct and an invoke method in the controller that are the exam same.

I've found this error in other posts, but what I am finding is issues with not passing something to the construct method and this seems to be the wrong arguments being passed to mine.

I don't want to have to pass the entire container into every controller as these controllers only need set dependencies and there is a lot of unnecessary items in there as far as the controllers are concerned.

Comment: Can you show your config where you define the `db` value.

Comment: I can.  I tested all of the dependencies and t hey work when used in test code.

`   // MySQL Database Setup
   $container['db'] = function($c)
   {
       $cfg = $c->get('settings')['db'];
       $dsn = "mysql:host={$cfg['host']};dbname={$cfg['dbname']}";
       $db = new PDO($dsn,$cfg['user'],$cfg['pass'],$cfg['opts']);
       return $db;
   };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly because Slim can not find `HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController` class in dependency container (because you registered it with string `'FacultyController'` instead of fully qualified name of class).

When Slim can not find it in dependency container, by default, Slim tries to create `HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController` on its own and pass container instance into `FacultyController` constructor. But because you declare constructor of `FacultyController` with typehint to `PDO` class, PHP complain about this type mismatch.

Solution is try to replace `'FacultyController'` with full name including namespace to make Slim can find controller in dependency container.

So instead of,

```
$container['FacultyController'] = function($c) {
     return new FacultyController(
         $c->get('db'), 
         $c->get('mongo'), 
         $c->get('appLogger'), 
         $c->get('secLogger')
     );
};
```

you should use

```
$container[\HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController::class] = function($c) {
     return new \HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController(
         $c->get('db'), 
         $c->get('mongo'), 
         $c->get('appLogger'), 
         $c->get('secLogger')
     );
};
```

or

```
use \HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController;

$container[FacultyController::class] = function($c) {
     return new FacultyController(
         $c->get('db'), 
         $c->get('mongo'), 
         $c->get('appLogger'), 
         $c->get('secLogger')
     );
};
```

Then in your route declaration, you may use, for example:

```
$app->get('/faculty', \HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController::class);
```

[More information about ::class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

**Update**

If you use code above, `FacultyController` is considered as invokable class, which means, it is expected to have `__invoke()` method implemented.

```
class FacultyController 
{
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $args)
    {
          //handle the request
    }
}
```

If you do not want to use invokable class but ordinary method to handle request, include method name when setup route

```
$app->get('/faculty', \HCC\API\Controllers\FacultyController::class . ':getFacultyCollection');
```

`getFacultyCollection()` method will be called to handle request.

```
class FacultyController 
{
    public function getFacultyCollection($request, $response, $args)
    {
          //handle the request
    }
}
```

If `getFacultyCollection()` call causes application to crash as you said in comment, then it is entirely different problem. Maybe you have unterminated loop?

[More information about __invoke() magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke)

Comment: When I try this I get:
 Type: RuntimeException
Message: [{},"__invoke"] is not resolvable
File: /var/projects/apollo/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
Line: 104
If I add :getFacultyCollection at the end of that I get a memory leak and the function gets called repeatively until the script crashes with out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Sorry that it has taken me so long to response, but this has been a crazy week and today I was only able to just get back to this issue.

the loop was a misplaced method call that ended up recalling the same method from within itself.  Once I corrected that and did the fix you provided before i am up and working now.

thank you for your help.